# Kernel Parameters in AArch64

Tags: pi-3, boot, kernel

My Raspberry Pi 3B runs fine with the standard installation of ArchLinuxARM-rpi-3-latest.tar.gz. However I cannot set kernel parameters anywhere for a custom TFT. Formerly there was a file cmdline.txt, which doesn't exist here. So where can I set this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't run fine, at least right now (March 2019). There is no CPU frequency governor, so your unit is prone to overheating (that's because the arm archlinux
kernel is built to run on multiple devices, not just for the rpi3). What you need to do, apparently, is to install a new `/boot` partition and kernel, after the initial install, or you can switch the provided one before the initial install. Check out the `AUR linux-aarch64-raspberrypi-bin` package. Then you will have the usual `cmdline.txt` and your pi won't burn up. The alternative is to use the `armv7` version.

EDIT: After some soul-searching I switched to Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit beta. This alleviates the need to most hacks and saves time.